# Convert yyyy-mm-dd-hh.mm.ss.ms String to Datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, view

I use SQL Server and have the string with this format:

```
2017-05-29-16.57.51.910000
```

And I must get the format like `2020-12-17 11:44:25.620` in my view.

How to do that?

Important for those who asking, **no typo, and pure copy paste from the data I got from the source data**

Comment: Is your first datetime a typo and supposed to look like '2017-05-29 16:57:51.910000' or is it literally in the format 2017-05-29-16.57.51.910000?

Specifically asking about the hyphen between the day and hour and the periods after the hours and minutes.

Comment: Fix the problem once by fixing your schema. Absent that, you need to replace that strange hypen between the day and hour with a space and then convert it using the appropriate style. But far better to let the consumer handle formatting and simply convert your string to an actual datetime2 datatype (using similar logic).

Comment: Not at all, no typo, and pure copy paste from the data I got. and thats the data I got from source.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're wanting to convert from the [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) format to the [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) format:

```
SELECT CAST(your_date AS datetime) FROM [your_table]
```

Comment: FYI, Datetime2 is like: 2017-05-29 16:57:51.9100000
and the format I got from source is not the same at all.. 
its: 2017-05-29-16.57.51.910000

Answer (score 0):

And i solved it with some poor command, just to make it works

```
CONVERT(datetimeoffset, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, convert(varchar, LEFT([UPDATE_DATE_TIME],10)+' '+REPLACE(left(Right([UPDATE_DATE_TIME],15),8),'.',':')+'.000')), '+07:00'))
```